# Hibernate Tools 5.3 - Mysql 8 - domain generation

Tags: java-8, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-tools, mysql-8.0

I try to generate java class from MySql 8.0.12 database by using Hibernate Tools on eclipse

Class are well generated but without annotations (like @Entity, etc...)

[image]

Here is my Hibernate Tools configuration :

[image]

[image]

I can ping database and retrieve tables :

[image]

Here is my hibernate code generation configuration :

[image]

and

[image]

I used to work with MySQL 5 and hibernate Tools 5.2 and it worked fine !
But now i would like to upgrade my database (MySql 8)

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I keep MySql 5.1 ...

Answer (score 1):

it is the Hibernate version 5.3. It is a bug.

I ran into the same problem.

Change it to 5.2 and it should work.

[See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50850406/9409095)